# Karma test coverage: Could not find source map

Tags: angular, karma-runner, karma-jasmine, karma-coverage

I get this error when I run my coverage. I still get a coverage report, but I'm not sure how accurate it is with this error. I have my repo here https://github.com/piq9117/codeCoverage

clone the repo:

`$ git clone https://github.com/piq9117/codeCoverage.git`

Install the dependencies:

`$ npm install`

Run the test:

`$ npm run test:single`

It will produce a coverage directory and the `coverage-final.json` but the test doesnt exit and instead give this error:

```
 Error: Could not find source map for: "C:\Users\Ken\Documents\codeCoverage\karma.entry.js"
    at C:\Users\Ken\Documents\codeCoverage\node_modules\remap-istanbul\lib\remap.js:213:11
    at Array.forEach (native)
    at C:\Users\Ken\Documents\codeCoverage\node_modules\remap-istanbul\lib\remap.js:192:22
    at Array.forEach (native)
    at remap (C:\Users\Ken\Documents\codeCoverage\node_modules\remap-istanbul\lib\remap.js:191:12)
    at KarmaRemapIstanbul.onRunComplete (C:\Users\Ken\Documents\codeCoverage\node_modules\karma-remap-istanbul\index.js:55:21)
    at Server.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Ken\Documents\codeCoverage\node_modules\karma\lib\events.js:13:22)
    at emitTwo (events.js:111:20)
    at Server.emit (events.js:191:7)
    at emitRunCompleteIfAllBrowsersDone (C:\Users\Ken\Documents\codeCoverage\node_modules\karma\lib\server.js:294:12)
    at Server.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Ken\Documents\codeCoverage\node_modules\karma\lib\server.js:325:7)
    at emitOne (events.js:96:13)
    at Server.emit (events.js:188:7)
    at Server.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Ken\Documents\codeCoverage\node_modules\karma\lib\server.js:308:12)
    at emitOne (events.js:101:20)
    at Server.emit (events.js:188:7)
20 12 2016 09:48:20.311:ERROR [karma]: TypeError: Cannot read property 'text' of undefined
    at C:\Users\Ken\Documents\codeCoverage\node_modules\istanbul\lib\report\html.js:288:53
    at Array.forEach (native)
    at annotateBranches (C:\Users\Ken\Documents\codeCoverage\node_modules\istanbul\lib\report\html.js:255:30)
    at HtmlReport.writeDetailPage (C:\Users\Ken\Documents\codeCoverage\node_modules\istanbul\lib\report\html.js:426:9)
    at C:\Users\Ken\Documents\codeCoverage\node_modules\istanbul\lib\report\html.js:489:26
    at SyncFileWriter.writeFile (C:\Users\Ken\Documents\codeCoverage\node_modules\istanbul\lib\util\file-writer.js:57:9)
    at FileWriter.writeFile (C:\Users\Ken\Documents\codeCoverage\node_modules\istanbul\lib\util\file-writer.js:147:23)
    at C:\Users\Ken\Documents\codeCoverage\node_modules\istanbul\lib\report\html.js:488:24
    at Array.forEach (native)
    at HtmlReport.writeFiles (C:\Users\Ken\Documents\codeCoverage\node_modules\istanbul\lib\report\html.js:482:23)
    at C:\Users\Ken\Documents\codeCoverage\node_modules\istanbul\lib\report\html.js:484:22
    at Array.forEach (native)
    at HtmlReport.writeFiles (C:\Users\Ken\Documents\codeCoverage\node_modules\istanbul\lib\report\html.js:482:23)
    at HtmlReport.writeReport (C:\Users\Ken\Documents\codeCoverage\node_modules\istanbul\lib\report\html.js:566:14)
    at C:\Users\Ken\Documents\codeCoverage\node_modules\remap-istanbul\lib\writeReport.js:77:22
    at C:\Users\Ken\Documents\codeCoverage\node_modules\remap-istanbul\node_modules\amdefine\amdefine.js:125:34
```